# Python TKinter weird behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have the below code in Python (v3.7 installed):

```
import datetime
import tkinter as tk

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, birthdate):
        self.name = name
        self.birthdate = birthdate

    def age(self):
        today = datetime.date.today()
        age = today.year - self.birthdate.year
        return age

window = tk.Tk()  # Create frame
window.geometry("400x400")  # Create frame geometry
window.title("Age Calculator App")  # Set title of the frame

# Add Labels
year_label = tk.Label(master=window, text="Year").grid(column=0, row=1)
month_label = tk.Label(master=window, text="Month").grid(column=0, row=2)
day_label = tk.Label(master=window, text="Day").grid(column=0, row=3)

# Add Entries
year_entry = tk.Entry()
year_entry.grid(column=1, row=1)
month_entry = tk.Entry()
month_entry.grid(column=1, row=2)
day_entry = tk.Entry()
day_entry.grid(column=1, row=3)

def calculate_age():
    print(year_entry.get())
    print(month_entry.get())
    print(day_entry.get())
    print("Button was clicked!!")

calculate_button = tk.Button(text="Calculate now", command=calculate_age).grid(column=1, row=4)  # Add calculate button
```

The code works fine and runs as expected, however, if I change these lines:

```
# Add Entries
year_entry = tk.Entry()
year_entry.grid(column=1, row=1)
month_entry = tk.Entry()
month_entry.grid(column=1, row=2)
day_entry = tk.Entry()
day_entry.grid(column=1, row=3)
```

And make them one-liners like so:

```
# Add Entries
year_entry = tk.Entry().grid(column=1, row=1)
month_entry = tk.Entry().grid(column=1, row=2)
day_entry = tk.Entry().grid(column=1, row=3)
```

I am getting the below error:

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "Python/lib/tkinter/**init**.py", line 1705, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "person_class.py", line 42, in
>   calculate_age
>       print(year_entry.get()) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

How is this possible? Shouldn't this be doable on a one-liner instead of having to split the entries into different lines?

Can someone explain me why is this weird behavior happening and how can I better make use of the one-liners when declaring stuff in Python 3.x?

Please note that I am a beginner in Python. In Java or Groovy, the one-liners would simply work as expected.

Comment: Your one-liners are not equivalent to the originals. When your code does `year_entry = tk.Entry()` you have a reference to a new `tk.Entry` object. The next line calls `.grid()` on that object. When your code does `year_entry = tk.Entry().grid(column=1, row=1)` it creates a new `tk.Entry` object, calls `.grid()` on it and *then throws away the reference to the `tk.Entry` object* and assigns the result of the `.grid()` call (which is `None`) to `year_entry`.

Comment: @BoarGules Thank you for being explicit. Would there be a chance you know if there is a particular reason for this poor design of ditching references like that? Or better yet, do you happen to know how I can force it to keep reference? Otherwise, kindly submit it as an answer so that I can mark it.

Comment: Note that this isn't a tkinter problem per se. In python, when you do `x().y()` no matter what `x()` and `y()` do, python will return the result of `y()`. In tkinter, `grid(...)` is defined to return `None`.

Comment: In Python (and Python is not alone in this) an assignment of an expression that is a chain of attributes, as in `a = b.c.d` will assign the value of `d` to `a`. I can't concur with you that it is poor design. If I do `a = os.path.exists('myfile')` I expect `a` to receive a boolean value reflecting the existence of `myfile`, *not* a reference to the module `os.path`. If PEP 572 makes it into Python 3.8 you will soon be able to do what you want this way: `(year_entry := tk.Entry()).grid(column=1, row=1)` but I still think your original formulation is better than any one-liner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because for reasons to me obscure tkinter loses the reference to the object

try it

```
# Add Labels
year_label = tk.Label(master=window, text="Year")
year_label.grid(column=0, row=1)
month_label = tk.Label(master=window, text="Month")
month_label.grid(column=0, row=2)
day_label = tk.Label(master=window, text="Day")
day_label.grid(column=0, row=3)

# Add Entries
  year_entry = tk.Entry()
  year_entry.grid(column=1, row=1)
  month_entry = tk.Entry().grid(column=1, row=2)
  day_entry = tk.Entry().grid(column=1, row=3)

def calculate_age():
    print(type(year_entry))
    print(type(month_entry))
    return
```

that return

class 'NoneType' for month_entry that is in line

class 'tkinter.Entry' for year_entry that isn't